# POSTGRESQL error column must appear in group by clause or be used in an aggregate function

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by

table salesorderheader:

```
-salesorderid
-orderdate
-customerid
-subtotal
```

table customer:

```
-customerid
-companyname
```

table company:

```
-id
-cname
```

code:

```
INSERT INTO company_abc (cid, salestotal, cls, year)
SELECT distinct com.id, SUM(soh.subtotal),
    CASE
        WHEN SUM(soh.subtotal) <= 0.8 * SUM(soh.subtotal) OVER (PARTITION BY EXTRACT(YEAR FROM soh.orderdate)) THEN 'A'
        WHEN SUM(soh.subtotal) <= 0.95 * SUM(soh.subtotal) OVER (PARTITION BY EXTRACT(YEAR FROM soh.orderdate)) AND SUM(soh.subtotal) > 0.8 * SUM(soh.subtotal) OVER (PARTITION BY EXTRACT(YEAR FROM soh.orderdate)) THEN 'B'
        ELSE 'C'
    END,
    EXTRACT(YEAR FROM soh.orderdate)
FROM salesorderheader soh
INNER JOIN customer c ON soh.customerid = c.customerid
INNER JOIN company com ON com.cname = c.companyname
GROUP BY com.id, EXTRACT(YEAR FROM soh.orderdate)
ORDER BY com.id, EXTRACT(YEAR FROM soh.orderdate) desc
```

error:

```
SQL Error [42803]: ERROR: column "soh.subtotal" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
  position: 150
error position: line: 4 pos: 149
```

I tried to add soh.subtotal in group by, but catched this error:

```
  Key (cid, year)=(1102, 2013) already exists.
```

Comment: The error is coming from `... 0.8 * SUM(soh.subtotal) OVER (PARTITION BY ...`. In other words from the window functions. To get a more detailed add example input data and expected output as a text update to your question. Though you might try with `<value> * SUM(soh.subtotal)` and  no `OVER ...` for each part of the `CASE`.

Answer (score 0):

Try some correction to query, as required by error message from DBMS.
Replace `soh.subtotal` in windows functions by `SUM(soh.subtotal)`.
`SELECT` part of query executed after `GROUP BY`. Accordingly, you mast use expressions like `SUM(something)`,`MIN(something)` in SELECT clause for values not included in GROUP BY clause. This is also true for WINDOWS functions with GROUP BY.

```
INSERT INTO company_abc (cid, salestotal, cls, year)
SELECT distinct com.id, SUM(soh.subtotal),
   CASE
      WHEN SUM(soh.subtotal) <= 0.8 * SUM(SUM(soh.subtotal))OVER(PARTITION BY EXTRACT(YEAR FROM soh.orderdate)) 
         THEN 'A'
      WHEN SUM(soh.subtotal) <= 0.95 * SUM(SUM(soh.subtotal))OVER(PARTITION BY EXTRACT(YEAR FROM soh.orderdate))
       AND SUM(soh.subtotal) > 0.8 * SUM(SUM(soh.subtotal))OVER(PARTITION BY EXTRACT(YEAR FROM soh.orderdate)) 
         THEN 'B'
  ELSE 'C'
  END,
  EXTRACT(YEAR FROM soh.orderdate)
FROM salesorderheader soh
INNER JOIN customer c ON soh.customerid = c.customerid
INNER JOIN company com ON com.cname = c.companyname
GROUP BY com.id, EXTRACT(YEAR FROM soh.orderdate)
ORDER BY com.id, EXTRACT(YEAR FROM soh.orderdate) desc;
```